# Pandas Binning Only Time Column Not Date From a Custom Range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time, time-series

I have a `timestamp_time` column in a DataFrame (in string format)

```
timestamp_time

11:59 AM
5:06 AM
11:04 PM
5:06 PM
....
....
12:00 AM
12:01 PM
```

I want to bin the values in these range (inclusive)

```
morning -> 5AM to 11:59AM
afternoon ->12PM to 4:59PM
evening -> 5PM to 8:59PM
night -> 9PM to 11:59PM
midnight -> 12AM to 4:59AM
```

I want to generate a new `time_of_the_day` column based on the value (and the mentioned range) from `timestamp_time` column

The Output will be like this

```
time_of_the_day

morning
morning
night
evening
....
....
midnight
afternoon
```

---

I converted the `timestamp_time` to 24-hour time format

What to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a function to transform a certain time to the time range(time_of_the_day)

```
def time_range(time):
    hour = datetime.strptime(time, '%I:%M %p').hour
    if hour > 20:
        return "Night"
    elif hour > 16:
        return "Evening"
    elif hour > 11:
        return "Afternoon"
    elif hour > 4:
        return "Morning"
    else:
        return "Midnight"
```

then use apply method using the function we created to transform you data, and set it your new column(feature)

```
df["time_of_the_day"] = df.timestamp_time.apply(lambda time: time_range(time))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly

Comment: am glad it helped you! 